# Magento 2 - Extension throws error during compilation, even though it is disabled

Tags: magento2, setup-di-compile

I try to compile my project with `bin/magento setup:di:compile`, but I get:

```
Company\PdfDesign\Block\Order
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data. Actual type: \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer; File:
/var/www/html/magento/app/code/Company/PdfDesign/Block/Order.php

Total Errors Count: 1

In Log.php line 92:

  Error during compilation
```

Even though the extension "Company/PdfDesign" was disabled from CLI.

I tried to delete the generated data with `rm -rf generated/code/* generated/metadata/*` and tried it again, but it makes no difference.

If I delete the module Company_PdfDesign then compilation runs through.

Comment: comment your extension's registration.php and module.xml and then try to run compile command.

Comment: Did you check the module status? php bin/magento module:status

Comment: @WangGang of course.